# mysql get the id of the name

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a Database like this:

```
ID Name Password
1  Hans  *****
```

Now when I login I get the PHP Session of the Name.

Now I want to get the ID of the I entered Name in the Login and saved in the NameSession, and save it to a SESSION too.

I have searched in the Internet because its looks not so hard, but I havent found anything .

This is my Code so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Login='".$loginname."' and Password = '".$loginpassword."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { //...wenn ein Datensatz mit diesem Nicknamen gefunden wurde:
    echo "Willkommen ".$loginname; //Fehlermeldung

    //Session registieren
    $_SESSION['loginname'] = $loginname;
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $User_ID;

    //Text ausgeben
header('Location: home.php');
exit();  
}
```

Comment: please format your question better.

Comment: Please avoid using _deprecated_ mysql functions and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Your table structure shows `ID Name Password` where as your query shows the column name as `Login and Password`. Whats happening?

Comment: The password and login Value will be entered in seperate login page.

Comment: @Syrakus How exactly does your table `Login` look like? what columns does it have?

Comment: Oh, now I see, sorry, Its User_ID , Login and Password
not ID , Name, Password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the corresponding `id` of the particular record.
Assuming that your table structure is `ID Name Password` as you mentioned in your question. According to which your SQL query should rather be like:

```
"SELECT * FROM login WHERE Name ='".$loginname."' and Password = '".$loginpassword."'";
```

Change this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { //...wenn ein Datensatz mit diesem Nicknamen gefunden wurde:
    echo "Willkommen ".$loginname;
```

to this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { //...wenn ein Datensatz mit diesem Nicknamen gefunden wurde:
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['ID'];

  //saving the id and username in sessions
  $_SESSION['loginname'] = $loginname;
  $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['ID'];
```

> Note: This is still bad practice, Kindly study `mysqli` or `PDO`.

[PHP Manual: MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[PHP Manual: PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: thank your really much, yeah youre right, I should be starting to learn PDO :D

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$_SESSION['UserID'] = $User_ID;
```

to

```
$_SESSION['UserID'] = $result['ID'];
```

or if you had included `explode($result)` after the sql query, the `$ID` variable would be available.

This is with the assumption that only 1 row has been returned from your query, you may want to perform a loop the `$result` array (all returned rows), depending on how far you want to go with the login workflow.